# Limits on Shikhiha Leket and Peah

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, leket-shichecha-peah

Massekhes Peah talks extensively about the amount of crop to be left by the farmer for Leket & Peah as well as what constitutes shikhiha.

Some one just asked me if there was a limit to the amount that any one ani could gather of any of Shikhiha Leket and Peah.  Meaning, if there is an ani who wants to take all of the peah from a single field is that ok?  My gut is telling me that there is a limit but I havent found it.

Comment: כל דאלים גבר! 15

Comment: so there is mamash no limit?  Wow I am surprised.

Comment: I don't have a source so I'm not posting as an answer, but if it's tzedaka for all poor people, I don't see why it would matter how much any one poor person takes, provided he doesn't take so much that he becomes too rich to take more. As long as only poor people take it, that fulfills the requirement.

Comment: that makes sense and it also connects in someways to the conversation around the possibility of hefker le'aniim.  IE can I be mafkir something only for a group of individuals.  You may be right but it doesnt sit well with me.

Answer (score 2):

From [the *Minchas Chinuch* (216)'s discussion of how a landowner can give out *pea* to paupers after he did not leave it in his field for them](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14092&st=&pgnum=11), it seems to me that he can give all of it to one pauper. I don't see why it'd be different when the pauper picks the crop himself, but I have no explicit source.